# Why is there a VM automatically created when creating an Azure AKS cluster

Tags: azure, azure-aks

When I deploy a new Kubernetes Service in Azure I recently discovered that Azure also deploys a VM, named "aks-agentpool-[8 digits]-[1 digit]".

Besides this VM being fairly costly (Standard F4s_v2 (4 vcpus, 8 GiB memory)), then I also have no control over whether it is created, and I am not even sure I can control its size.

My question is: **Why is this VM created?** AKS is a managed service so I don't think I should need a VM for the service itself, only the containers

**UPDATE:** Based on the first answers can see I am missing a bit of information. When I deploy I am already specifying VM size and node pools, so **why is a default VM created for me right away?** I never specify very big VMs when deploying my containers, so the the huge F4s machine that Azure creates is a complete waste.

Comment: if you specify a vm size when you create AKS it will use that vm size, for example when using the portal you can accept the default or change it, but with powershell\cli you can amend it and the default will be used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AKS nodes run on Azure virtual machines. You can refer to this doc of AKS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/intro-kubernetes

[image]

You can specify the vm's size by this tutorial:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-multiple-node-pools#specify-a-vm-size-for-a-node-pool

Answer (score 1):

exactly, vms are there to host your containers. only the masters\etcd are managed. not the worker nodes